# Как отловить SQLiteConstraintException в Room Database

Tags: java, android, android-room

У меня есть слудущая `Entity`

```
@Entity
public class UserWorkplace {

    @NonNull
    @PrimaryKey
    @SerializedName("Id")
    @Expose
    private String id;


    @NonNull
    @SerializedName("Description")
    @Expose
    private String description;


    @NonNull
    @SerializedName("UserProfileId")
    @Expose
    private String userProfileId;

    @NonNull
    @SerializedName("Name")
    @Expose
    private String name;

    public UserWorkplace() {
    }

}
```

и DOA класс дле нее c методом:

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
abstract void insertUserWorkplaces(UserWorkplace userWorkplace);
```

и в случаее когда я пытаюсь сохранить такую `Entity` с полем `name = null`, я получаю ошибку:

> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: NOT NULL
>   constraint failed: UserWorkplace.name (Sqlite code 1299), (OS error -
>   2:No such file or directory)

**Вопрос:** Каким образом можно отлавиить данное исключение, я слыхал про  `insertOrThrow` но это в чистом `sqlite`, как можно это сделать в `Room Database` ?

Comment: а в чем конкретно проблема "отловить" исключение? Почему не сделать это допустим в сервисе? Или сделать ещё один слой, который будет вызывать ДАО, но на этом слое прописать обработку sql исключение и перевод его в исключение бизнес логики?

Comment: @Виктор Нет никакой проблемы сделать так, как вы говорите, просто предполагалось что есть какие то стандартные методы или аннотации для вызова методов которые броссают исключения.Но на сколько я уже монял, достаточно просто в метод DAO добавить к сигнатуре метода throws SQLiteConstraintException